# Rolling a three sided die six times?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider the problem of a rolling a three-sided die six times (independently). The probability of seeing 1 is 0.5, 2 is 0.25, and 3 is 0.25. With this model, I have been given the claim that:

> We know that there are $6\choose{2}$ ways of rolling exactly two
>   1's.

This does not look right to me. If it was a coin-tossing model with binary outcomes, that would be right.

But since we have 3 outcomes for each roll, we can count the set of all length-6 rolls with two 1's by first specifying the index position of the two 1's $6\choose2$ ways, and then the outcome of the remaining four rolls (which has $2^4$ ways), for a total of $2^4\times {6\choose2}$ ways.

Is this reasoning correct?

Note: The motivation is question 2 from this [problem](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn04.pdf) and [solution](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn04_sol.pdf) on OpenCourseWare.

Comment: What does a three-sided die look like? A Toblerone chocolate bar still in its wrapping?

Comment: Depends on what the sample space is. With the "natural" sample space of all words of length $6$ over the alphabet $\{1,2,3\}$, your answer is right. If we use a sample space of words made up of the letters Y (getting a $1$) and N (not a $1$) then $\binom{6}{2}$ is right. Disadvantage of this sample space is that the elements are not equiprobable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key seems to be in the sentence (from the linked-to solution) that *precedes* what you quoted:

> For the purposes of solving this problem we treat obtaining a 2 or 3
>   as an equivalent result.

In other words, they are reducing things to the coin-tossing model.